# angular injection error: failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to separate my angular app out into its own file but now getting dependency injection error and not sure why. Simplified `angular-app.js` and error below:

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider'], function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/browse/overview.html');
})
```

and error:

```
Failed to instantiate module angularApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=u...)
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:35:350
    at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:34:428)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:35:93
    at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:34:428)
    at Lb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:38:146)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:17:339
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is on this line:

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider'], function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
```

You need to close the bracket after the function declaration, like this:

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/browse/overview.html');
}])
```